# In Python3, is `urllib.request` thread-safe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread-safety, urllib, python-multithreading

It's not found if `urllib.request` is **thread-safe** or not in Python 3 [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html). Is there anything special that I have to look for when using it in multi-threading scripts?

Answer (score 0):

According to `urllib.request`'s source [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/urllib/request.py#l1642), [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/urllib/request.py#l1978) and [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/urllib/request.py#l1497), no, it isn't.

In general, Python is *not* thread safe, so unless explicitly stated that a module is, you should assume it isn't.

Comment: Comments in source you mentioned are related to FTP access, so what about HTTP? is `urllib.request` use `http.client` as backend?